# Inductor value for power supply design

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-regulator, inductor

I am designing a power supply card using [V7805-2000](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiB2u3V0qfsAhUOxTgGHYhVAmYQFjACegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cui.com%2Fproduct%2Fresource%2Fv78xx-2000.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3NLtLGJsfD8acFk35J3G3S) for 12V to 5V conversion. In the datasheet on page number 6 they have a recommended input filter and output filter circuit. For the inductor they have mentioned value between 10uH to 47uH.

The input to the V7805 will be 12V@2A. I used 0805 footprint for the inductor in input and output path.

I am unable to find the part number for matching the recommended value(10uH to 47uH) in 0805 package at the input and output current rates of 2A. I want to use an inductor current rated twice the needed current rating to be on the safer side.

What happens if I use this [Inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/LPWI201210HR47T/9996635) in both input and output path?

Comment: If you absolutely have to use 0805 pads, you might be able to get this inductor to fit:https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/DFE252012P-4R7M=P2/5247262

Comment: Isn't an 0805 footprint a bit small for what you need ? Why do you even need the inductors anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

> *What happens if I use this [Inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/LPWI201210HR47T/9996635) in both input and output path?*

The inductor you linked is 0.47 uH so, it will be ineffective as a filter but have no problems with the operating current.

> *I am unable to find the part number for matching the recommended
> value(10uH to 47uH) in 0805 package at the input and output current
> rates of 2A.*

Yes, that doesn't surprise me - you'll have to choose a bigger package.

Comment: I am replacing 0805 footprint with this inductor:-  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/74437349100/2791023

Comment: Be aware that if you are hoping it will work above 12 MHz, this won't happen because its self resonant frequency is 12 MHz at which it turns into a high impedance (a good thing) but, as frequency increases, it turns into a capacitor. Probably OK for most applications though.

Comment: I will  keep that in mind!